# moderncv social symbol not horizontal aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv

I finally managed to include my "Xing" social icon with link in the header of my moderncv. I had to do it like that since I didn't manage to get fontawesome to work (tried a lot; compiled with LuaLaTeX etc.).
I'm almost happy with how it is now but recognized that the Xing icon is too high and not properly aligned horizontally with the linkedin icon. How can I manage that my artificially inserted Xing icon is in line with the linkedin icon?
My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 

\usepackage{lastpage}
\rfoot{\addressfont\itshape\textcolor{gray}{Seite \thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}}
\pageref{LastPage}}}


%----------------- Header with picture ------------------------
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}{\par\vskip1ex\titlestyle{\@title}}{}{}          % activate for two lines
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstylebanking}{%
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
{\centering\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}\par\vspace{10pt}}%
\oldmakecvtitle%
}%
}{%
}
\newcommand*{\xingsocialsymbol}{\includegraphics[height=.7\baselineskip]{xing-logo}}
\collectionadd[xing]{socials}{ \href{<URL>}{john.doe}}
\makeatother
%----------------- Header mit Bild ------------------------

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Doe} % Your last name

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Street}{City}
\mobile{number}
\email{john.doe@gmail.com}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
\social[linkedin]{john-doe}
%\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[170pt][0pt]{landscape}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

\section{Text}

\end{document}
```

This gives me compiled with PDFLaTeX  (which I would prefer to do for some reason):

[image]

I hope someone can help. This is my first post but this site and the people here have been an awesome help for me as LaTeX beginner...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `\raisebox` down of 0.165em your icon, as in the [source](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncviconsmarvosym.sty):

```
\newcommand*{\xingsocialsymbol}{\protect\raisebox{-0.165em}{\includegraphics[height=.7\baselineskip]{xing-logo}}}
```